# linear gradient calculation for pie slices

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

We are rendering 64 pie pieces and wants a perfect linear gradient out from the middle for each pice.

Right now it looks like this if I copy the SVG to illustrator, as you can see the gradient is not perfectly aligned in the blue highlighted pice:
[image]

What we need is a more precise calculation for the pieces like this one.
[image]

This is the code we are using so far. What we need is a calculation of the gradientAngle that makes the gradients more aligned to the center

```
var total=64
  , center_x=options.center_x
  , center_y=options.center_y
  , radie=options.radie
  , val = 360 / total;

for (var i=0; total>=i; i++) {
    var start=val*i
      , gradientAngle=val*(total-i)
      , angle = (start + val % 360) * Math.PI / 180;

   renderPiePiece(center_x, center_y, radie, start, start+val, gradientAngle);
}

function renderPiePiece(center_x, center_y, radie, start_angle, end_angle, gradientAngle) {
    var flag = (end_angle - start_angle) > 180;
    start_angle = (start_angle % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    end_angle = (end_angle % 360) * Math.PI / 180;

    this.paper
        .path(
            ["M", center_x, center_y,
            "l", radie * Math.cos(start_angle), radie * Math.sin(start_angle), 
            "A", radie, radie, 0, +flag, 1, center_x + radie * Math.cos(end_angle), center_y + radie * Math.sin(end_angle), 
            "z"]
        ).attr({
            stroke:'black',
            "stroke-width":1,
            fill:gradientAngle+'-#fff:0-#000'
        });
    }
```

Here is one more example how it looks right now. As you can see the gradient is not perfectly from the center.
[image]

And here is a link to the script:
http://jsbin.com/bakinikadi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big solution but more a way around the problem.

make all the parts with gradient at zero and then rotate them.

```
var total=30;
var center_x=200;
var center_y=200;
var radie=200;
var val = 360 / total;
for (var i=0; total>=i; i++) {
  var start=val*(total-0.5);
  rot = (val*0.5)+(i*val)
  renderPiePiece(center_x, center_y, radie, start, val*0.5, 0, rot);
}
function renderPiePiece(center_x, center_y, radie, start_angle, end_angle, gradientAngle, rotation) {
  var flag = (end_angle - start_angle) > 180;
  start_angle = (start_angle % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
  end_angle = (end_angle % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
  paper
    .path(
      ["M", center_x, center_y,
        "l", radie * Math.cos(start_angle), radie * Math.sin(start_angle), 
        "A", radie, radie, 0, +flag, 1, center_x + radie * Math.cos(end_angle), center_y + radie * Math.sin(end_angle), 
        "Z"]
    ).attr({
      stroke:'black',
      "stroke-width":1,
      fill:gradientAngle+'-#fff-#000'
    }).transform("r"+rotation+","+center_x+","+center_y);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/jtfkadmy/